# DTD security error when i apply an XSLT stylesheet

Tags: c#, xslt, xslt-1.0, dtd

I got an error that i can't solve for the moment

The code :

```
var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load(stylesheet);
myXslTrans.Transform(sourceFile , outputFile);
```

The error :

> For safety reasons, DTC prohibited in this XML document To enable DTD
>   processing , set on the Parse DtdProcessing property XmlReaderSettings
>   and pass parameters to the XmlReader.Create method

I have tried with the XmlReaderSettings (DtdProcessing, DtdProcessing.Parse) but i didn't find the answer

Answer (score 0):

If the stylesheet document uses a DTD (e.g. has `<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet ...>`) then load it with

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(stylesheet, new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse }))
{
  myXslTrans.Load(xr);
}
```

If the sourceFile uses a DTD then load it with such an `XmlReader` passed as the first argument to the `Transform` method, you might then need a different overload of that method for the second and third argument.